# Node.js - Standard Library

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way in Node.js to define a "Standard Library", which is automatically executed at the start of every Node.js App?

For example:

```
//stdlibrary.js
function sayHello(){
   console.log("Hello World!");
}

//app.js
sayHello(); //without including the stdlibrary.js!
```

Hope my question is clear.

Thanks for your help!

**Update**

I´m looking for something like the `auto_prepend_file` in PHP. Hope there is something similar to this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is simple to do. Just edit the src/node.cc file to include an option for an autorequire file, and then modify the node::Load code to handle the option. You probably also need to change the javascript in src/node.js.

Rebuild, test and you are done.

Or you could probably just hack this into src/node.js by having it eval a string that requires your library and then evals the actual script file mentioned on the command line.

Comment: There is a cleaner way to do it: [Put your modified version of src/node.js to lib/_third_party_main.js](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/496be457b6a2bc5b01ec13644b9c9783976159b2)

Comment: Thank you. This is a correct answer. But I will not modify the source code of node.js. I'll include a standard file at the start of every app now.

Comment: Personally, I think that it would be very reasonable to modify node.js to include this capability as a command line option. It would not penalize anyone who doesn't use the feature and would be useful for creating domanin specific languages with node.js.

Answer (score 3):

There's no such thing in node.js, this kind of magic is not transparent and because of this reason gladly avoided by the most software products.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to create a file common.js that you include in each other file:

```
var common = require("./common")
```

You can then access constants and functions that are exported in common.js as follows:

```
common.MY_CONST
common.my_fun()
```

common.js would be implemented like:

```
exports.MY_CONST = 123
exports.my_fun = function() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is correct, but doesn´t do what I want. With this code I have to include it in every start file. Isn´t there a way to avoid this?

Comment: @FlashFan No, that's not possible. But I think it's a much better practice to add the explicit require() at the beginning of each file. Other people will have less trouble understanding your code. From the [Zen of Python](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/): "Explicit is better than implicit."

Comment: I know this, but I wanted to include my own library system as a standard library. So I would never need to use the "require" thing. But now, I´ll need it exactly 1x in all of my node apps :P

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to 'pollute' the global namespace (but it is not recommended at all). You could define an object containing your functions in a file (let's call it global.js):

global.js:

```
global.customNs = {};
global.customNs.helloparam = function(param) {
  console.log('Hello ' + param);
};
```

In your mainfile (your server or whatever kind of app you are developing), you require that file once:

server.js

```
require('./global');
```

After requiring it, you can access your global.customNs.helloparam function in all following requires (basically everywhere).

Another option is to define a global object using CommonJS module notation:

global.js

```
exports.customNs = {
  global.customNs.helloparam = function(param) {
    console.log('Hello ' + param);
  };
}
```

server.js

```
globalObject = require('./global').customNs;
```

Then access it using globalObject.helloparam('test') anywhere in your require'd code.

Note: i don't use either of those in production code, just threw this examples together using some testing code. Can't guarantee they work under any circumstances